# How to print the public details like first name, last name or email in Facebook SDK 4.18.0 in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am integrating facebook login in Swift3 language in iOS using FBSDK4.18.0.Below is the following code: But it does
not prints the results including

```
     func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("User Logged In")
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile")
            {
                // Do work
//                let strFirstName: [String: Any]? = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
//                let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
//                let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!

                if let dic = result as? [String: Any]
                { if let strFirstName = dic["first_name"] as? String, let strLastName = dic["last_name"] as? String
                {
                    print("\(strFirstName) \(strLastName)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It also shows the  "**Cast from 'FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails**" warning at "if let dic = result as? [String: Any]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `AnyObject` and not `Any`. More on it can be found [here](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/any-vs-anyobject-in-swift-3-b1a8d3a02e00#.jvf8os4ok):

```
if let dic = result as? [String: AnyObject] { 
   if let strFirstName = dic["first_name"] as? String, let strLastName = dic["last_name"] as? String
       {
          print("\(strFirstName) \(strLastName)")
       }
 }
```